# VLOOKUP does not work on other workbook and returns 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I try to make VBA to perform a VLOOKUP, however, the table for VLOOKUP is in another workbook.

When I record macro on the main workbook and generate VLOOKUP from dialogue box, it works. I can also fill the other rows and colums by simply dragging the active cell. When I stop recording macro, the result in VBA console can be found below;

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC3,'[sales 2009-2018.xlsx]sales 31122009'!R1C1:R546753C21,R1C,0)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N3:N19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("N3:N19").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N3:AC19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("N3:AC19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("N3").Select
```

Thus, it goes to "sales 2009-2018.xlsx" for the data for VLOOKUP.

However, when I run the macro to perform the same function it gives me the following error;

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Why macro gives this error when running while it works perfectly when I record it?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Best regards,

Comment: See ["**How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA**"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/8112776).

Comment: Do you have the sales 2009-2018.xlsx workbook open?

Comment: Yes, "sales 2009-2018.xlsx" is already open. Some part of the code does it before reaching this part of the code.

Comment: Can you read [mcve] and come up with one?

Comment: Your macro was recorded in a particular cell. When you then run it, if you are not in the same cell you may get unusual results. Far better to replace activecell in the first line with an explicit statement about the cell you want : probably Range("n2") ?

Comment: I put Range("N3").Select before VLOOKUP in order to be in the same cell I record it, however, it gives the same error. @Harassed Dad

Comment: Try running the macro by clicking in the code and pressing F8. You can step through the code line by line by successive pressing of F8 until you get the error. The line in yellow is the source of the problem and will narrow it down.